TypeScript null check for parent object of a mutable location
I have a React app using TypeScript 4.8.4.
import { isNil } from "lodash";  // isNil(value: any): value is null | undefined

const order = ...  // { uuid: string } | null

const { data } = useOrderQuery(
  isNil(order?.uuid)
    ? { skip: true }
    : { variables: { uuid: order.uuid } },  // variables requires { uuid: string }
);

If !isNil(order?.uuid), order.uuid is a string, which means that order must not be null (if it was null, the optional chaining would produce undefined for order.uuid).
However, tsc flags the order.uuid access on the last line, saying error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
I think this is because order.uuid is a mutable location (I may be wrong). If that's the case, why does TypeScript think it's possible for the type to change in between the ternary condition and the false branch of the ternary?
There are lots of changes to the condition that fix this (isNil(order) || isNil(order.uuid), test a new orderUuid variable, order?.uuid === null || order?.uuid === undefined, etc), but they're all more verbose.
VSCode doesn't complain (I think it's using the latest TypeScript version).
Upgrading my TypeScript version fixes this (this is fixed somewhere between 5.2.1 and 5.3.3), but I'd love to find a fix that works for my current version, or at least understand the issue better.

Is this question about react or lodash? If so, please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't reference them, so that nobody needs to involve them in their testing or investigation.  My IDE doesn't know what useOrderQuery is, and presumably that's not the point of your question.

Please see prev comment.  The issue is microsoft/TypeScript#34974. TypeScript did not understand the implications of optional chaining not being undefined as a type guard on the original thing. Such implications need to be programmed into TypeScript explicitly. This was done in microsot/TypeScript#55613 which was released with TS5.3. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz — that's perfect, thanks for the link! Feel free to respond and I'll mark it as answered

I will do so when I get a chance; it's my bed time now so it will be a number of hours.

You're encountering microsoft/TypeScript#35974 in which the effects of a custom type guard function did not propagate up through an optional chaining expression. It isn't that TypeScript thought it was "possible" for the narrowed value to get re-widened in the middle of your expression; it's that TypeScript didn't really perform the narrowing you were expecting at all. Such narrowings don't happen automatically in TypeScript merely by logical implication; they need to be explicitly implemented in the compiler.
And this narrowing was, indeed, implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#55613, which was released with TypeScript 5.3. So the recommended way to deal with this is to keep your version of TypeScript up to date. This isn't always easy, but the language moves fast enough that dependencies on a particular version of the language tends to accumulate technical debt quickly.  If you're stuck on TypeScript 5.2 or below, then you'll need to modify your code in some way. The easiest approach is to just use a non-null assertion (!) like { variables: { uuid: order!.uuid } } and move on.
Playground link to code

As you are just using the value here, the most straightforward option would be to assign your uuid to a const like so:


import { isNil } from "lodash";  // isNil(value: any): value is null | undefined

const uuid = order?.uuid   // { uuid: string } | null

const { data } = useOrderQuery(
    isNil(uuid)
        ? { skip: true }
        : { variables: { uuid } },  // variables requires { uuid: string }
);



This way, typescript will be sure that no change to the object has occurred while processing the ternary.

why does TypeScript think it's possible for the type to change in
between the ternary condition and the false branch of the ternary?

Think of async functions in your code: When such a function changes your object, the condition might not hold any more at the time you are actually using its properties.

This way you might not even need lodash as you could just go with useOrderQuery(uuid ? { skip: true } … 

"the condition might not hold any more at the time you are actually using its properties.": that is true indeed if there is a possible time gap between the condition and the usage. But here the 2 occur in the same synchronous code block; JS being monothread, no other code could have run in between to change the value, therefore you are 100% sure that the check is still valid. Otherwise no type guard at all could provide any form of reliable information.

Yes and no, I think. It is even possible to break this in completely sync code: https://jsfiddle.net/muellerphilipp/cza3xf91/7/
Even though, this is a slightly artificial example, typing is all about preventing errors and this could be an error source.

Obviously if you introduce any obscure code (any function is enough) after your type guard, the result of the latter is invalidated. TS correctly takes this conservative approach: https://tsplay.dev/wQBbVN

IIUC the last part of your comment, you seem to imply that the only reliable solution is to use the const approach, which indeed entirely avoids this issue. But OP explicitly specifies that they are not interested with that one. OP's type guard on object property is as much reliable, as long as it keeps simple code.

Naaah, not my intention; sorry if it looked like that. I am with you, all clean code is fine. TBH I just overread OPs "I know the const option but don't want to use it".
